# Docker Compose with Apache attempting to cURL a subdomain

Tags: php, docker, curl

I have set up a docker-compose file that allows for all the projects at work to be spun up in one place easily with the correct versions of PHP all in one go. There is only one apache container that contains all the host files and matches them to the correct php file.

I am currently running into the problem where the webapp is trying to cURL the api to get data from it but everytime it is saying unable to resolve api.localhost, I thought i could get it working with `api.host.docker.internal` or something along those lines but I cant.
docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php70
      - php71
      - php72
      - php73
      - php74
      - php81
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  mariadb:
    build:
      context: ./${DOCKER_FOLDER}/mariadb
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
        - MARIADB_VERSION=${MARIADB_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MARIADB_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "${MARIADB_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MARIADB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MARIADB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MARIADB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - backend
  php70:
    build: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/php/PHP7.0'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  php71:
    build: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/php/PHP7.1'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  php72:
    build: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/php/PHP7.2'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  php73:
    build: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/php/PHP7.3'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  php74:
    build: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/php/PHP7.4'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  php81:
    build: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/php/PHP8.1'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Apache config:

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php70:9000/var/www/html/app/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/
    ServerName app.localhost
    <Directory /var/www/html/app/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Which one of your docker services is the api service?

Comment: @Arik The apache container contains all the services, "api", "web", "cms" etc. Which are then mapped to different localhosts: api.localhost, cms.localhost

Comment: So the "api" for example is not a real docker service, but an alias to the the real docker service that is called php7. So I think you have a typo and webapp.localhost should be an alias to php71 not php7.1

Comment: OK I think i may have confused things with wrong teminalogy, i have updated the question. The problem is that inside the apache config there is a .conf file for app.localhost and a .conf file for api.localhost. We can connect to them fine in the browser but when the app.localhost tries to curl to api.localhost it fails saying wrong host. @Arik

Comment: Which docker service has the host file that maps between "api.localhost" and the "php7" hostname?

Comment: The apache config files define what php docker container to use using the ProxyPassMatch

Comment: When you're using cURL to access "api.localhost", it will try to resolve its ip. I don't see where you define the association between "api.localhost" and the ip of "php7"

Comment: How would I go about defining that? @Arik

Comment: Can you use `php7` as the hostname in your cURL command instead of api.localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this by adding `extra_hosts` to a service. Example based on your code below. This does require you to know how to get your Docker Host IP which someone out there on stackoverflow will have covered better then I can.

Once you have your Docker Host IP I would suggest saving it in an .env file and reference it from there in the docker-compose.yml file as this will change over time.

```
php70:
build: './${DOCKER_FOLDER}/php/PHP7.0'
networks:
  - backend
volumes:
  - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
extra_hosts:
  - 'app.localhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}'
```